# How to add a new view to the Field Explorer in Crystal Reports

Tags: view, crystal-reports

I have created a new view and want to add it to an existing crystal report.  In the Database Expert there are options to add a new table but not a new view.  I want to select fields from the view, not the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Views are also allowed to be added in the Database Expert. Look into the Crystal Reports Options in the Crystal Reports menu. (Are you using Crystal Reports or Visual Studio?). There will be options to select object types in the database options.

If you create a view after you connect to the database from the Crystal Reports, you may not see the new views. For the views to be visible, go to Database menu and click verify. This will make the new views visible to you.

Otherwise, see if the user you are using to connect to the SQL server has adequate grants to see, use the views or not.

Comment: I am using Crystal Reports.  In the database options, I have both Tables and Views selected for Data Explorer.  In the Database Expert I can browse for tables to add but I don't see any of the views to select.

Answer (score 0):

If the new view is not visible from within Crystal then try following this menu path:

Database->Verify Database - This will refresh the database.  Then select Database->Add Database to Report...this will open the data explorer and the new view should be visible.